# Flutter/Dart: Navigator routes always take me to home screen with the selectedIndex = 0

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I am having an issue within my app where when I navigate to a screen within my HomeScreen, `e.g Navigator.of(context).push_________(Screen.routeName)` and click back on the app bar, it always takes me to the HomeScreen with the selectedIndex of the HomeScreen equal to 0. This might be an easy solution I'm fairly new to programming. I believe it has something to do with the fact that `selectedValue` is initialized to 0 in my **`HomeScreen<State> class`**.

Here's my code. I think I just need to make that value depends on where I navigate BACK from..(I want to go back to whatever index I Navigated from.

For example, if I am on `_selectedIndex = 2`, and I click to go into a screen within `_selectedIndex = 2` when I click the back button, I want to go back to the HomeScreen but with `_selectedIndex = 2`

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0; <--------------------------
static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[

  Screen1(), //index 0

  Screen2(), //index 1

  Screen3(), //index 2

  Screen4(), //index 3

  Screen5(), //index 4
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final authData = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: true);
  final filters = Provider.of<Filters>(context, listen: true);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
body: Center(
      child:
         _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      elevation: 0,
      iconSize: 22,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, 
          color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, 
          color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, 
          color: _selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, 
          color: _selectedIndex == 3 ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, 
          color: _selectedIndex == 4 ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
```

I navigate from _selectedIndex = 2 (the third tab) to a screen within _selectedIndex = 2 like this

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ChatScreen.routeName);
```

And then from that screen when I click the back button on the appBar which onPressed is defined as

```
leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } ),
```

It takes me back to the HomeScreen but with selectedIndex = 0. I want to go back to selectedIndex = 2.

Comment: Where is the part where you do the navigating?

Comment: Where's the part where you are changing the value of `_selectedIndex`?

Comment: Checkout following link. It is written for BottomNavigation but it might work for you https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1

Comment: @Abion47 that's thing I'm not and I'm not sure where/how to change the value

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu that article is about keeping state between two pages. See his ListView example so you know what I mean

Comment: @Tiny You can change it anywhere you want, but the place that makes the most sense would probably be within the `onPressed` method. Remember to surround it with a `setState` so the widget properly rebuilds afterwards.

Comment: yes but it's occurring on a different screen. so should I make the _selectedValue global? in other words, how am I going to access that property. its inside HomeScreen.dart and I am navigating from a screen called ChatScreen.dart which is inside of _selectedIndex = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share us your `_onItemTapped` method?

If you're just using `Navigator.push`, `Navigator.pushNamed` or navigating **without disposing** the previous route, then using `Navigator.pop()` alone should do the job. Exiting the current route whilst persisting the previous route's state.

However, since you are already using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), I suggest using it all the way for handling screen wide or global states.

Here's an example how you can achieve that:

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class AppNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  void changeSelectedIndexPage(int index) {
    selectedIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AppNotifier(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeScreenState();
  }
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  static List<Widget> _childWidgets = <Widget>[
    HomePage(),
    SettingsPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppNotifier _appNotifier = Provider.of<AppNotifier>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: _childWidgets.elementAt(_appNotifier.selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _appNotifier.selectedIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          _appNotifier.changeSelectedIndexPage(index);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            title: Text("Home"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
            title: Text("Settings"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => JustAnotherNewScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text("Open new page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Let's create a new instance of the other screen
            // And destroy home's screen instance
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => JustAnotherNewScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text("Open new page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class JustAnotherNewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.pop(context);
            // Let's create a new instance of the home page
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => HomeScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Just another new page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```